# Does the Remarkable Recovery feat cause you to regain hit points when you stabilize as a result of rolling your third successful death saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, saving-throw

The Remarkable Recovery feat from *Tal’dorei Campaign Setting: Reborn* says:

> When you are successfully stabilized while dying, you regain hit points equal to [...]

It's unclear to me whether this wording means somebody must stabilize you, or whether it comes into effect any time you stabilize for any reason.

The *Player's Handbook* Ch. 9 says, under **Death Saving Throws**:

> On your third success, you become stable (see below).

Does rolling your third success count qualify for hit points from the feat, or would the feat need to say something like "when you stabilize while dying" or "when you become stable while dying" for self-stabilization to be eligible?

Comment: Related, but not about self-stabilization: [Does Spare the Dying count as "stabilizing" or not?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/201232/does-spare-the-dying-count-as-stabilizing-or-not)

Comment: This feat also lets you add your Con mod to any magical healing received (actually, "from a spell, potion, or class feature", excluding from this feat but it's already not one of those things).  That makes Goodberry super good, like Life Cleric good, for out-of-combat healing.  Also, Lay On Hands, 1 HP at a time with a +3 Con mod gives you 4x the amount of healing.  That seems pretty strong for a half-feat on top of the stabilization benefit that makes Spare the Dying work as a heal, allowing indefinite whack-a-mole if the situation arises.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You regain hitpoints

**Death Saving Throws** on page 197 says (emphasis added):

> On your third success, you become stable (**see below**).

The "see below" refers to the section **Stabilizing a Creature** on the same page, that says

> A **stable** creature doesn’t make death saving throws, even though it has 0 hit points, but it does remain unconscious

There is no differnce between becoming stabilized by the help of others, or by saving throw successes, they refer to the same thing.

The Tal'Dorei text does not say that someone else needs to stabilize you. It just says you "are stabilized" instead of you "are stable". You also are stablized when you make three successful death saves. The language might have been technically clearer by saying you become stable, but as this happens in the moment you become stable, it may read a bit more naturally to say become stabilized.

Also, think of it that way: you have a player who is dying (most likely in combat), and just managed to make his third saving throw, and he has a feature that allows him to get back into the action. Do you really want to tell him "no, the language is not 100% clear the feature allows you to do that, I rule you stay down out"? I can tell you right now that this will lead to an unhappy player and bad interaction, and rightfully so.

Comment: Doesn’t that logic imply that being healed for at least one hit point also stabilizes a creature?

Comment: You only can be stable if you are at 0 hit points. If you are healed for at least one hit point, you are not stabilized or stable any more.

Comment: Don't they pass the stable threshold the moment they stop being unstable (IE making death saves) if they are healed?

Comment: @SeriousBri there is no point where you can be stable/stabilized and over 0 hp. A stable creature by definition is at 0 hp. Once you gain a hitpoint, you are not stabilized or stable, you are normal, at 1 hp. There is no “threshold” for being stablized, and no point in between where you are at 0 hp and stable when you move from 0 hp and dying to 1 hp and normal by receiving healing.

Comment: If OP quoted the rules text correctly, it does not say "become stabilized", it says "are successfully stabilized".

Comment: I think the argument in the last paragraph about how it plays to make the game fun, and probable design intent, is sufficient argument to conclude that you should pop up.  But as @FerventHippo points out, the actual wording of the feat implies that stabilizing has to be a result of someone actively doing it.  You could easily read that as not applying on its own, if you don't consider the fun-for-the-player aspect.  Narratively it could make sense that quick recovery brings you to consciousness, or that only a medicine check or magic like Spare the Dying or a Periapt of Wound Closure
work.

Comment: I think the word “successfully” implies it has to be the result of a stabilisation check; while you can succeed on a death saving throw, “successfully stabilised” implies an attempt to stabilise a character that might not succeed - i.e. an action from another character. But I agree on the RAI and RAF interpretation, but the RAW doesn’t support it well.

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie I’m not shy about accepting a different answer, in case you want to submit that as one.

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie why would you not be able to successfully stabilize with saving throws? Success and failure is the exact language the rules use for saves, and death saves are saves.